# What method can be used to print multiple eclust plots on one page?

Tags: r

Expected outcome of the script:

[image]

I am trying to get several clustering plots from eclust printed on one page, but unable to do it using multiple methods.

```
#install.packages("gridExtra")`
#install.packages("factoextra")`
#install.packages("eclust")`
#install.packages("ggplotify")`

require(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(lattice)
library(factoextra)
library(ggplotify)

#KMEANS -----------------------------
km <- eclust(tsne_df, "kmeans", k = NClust)
km.sil <- fviz_silhouette(km)

#PAM CLUSTERING ---------------------
pam <- eclust(tsne_df, "pam", k = NClust)
pam.sil <- fviz_silhouette(pam)

#METHOD_1
grid.arrange(grob(km), grob(pam), ncol=2)

#METHOD_2
multiple_plot <- arrangeGrob(grob(km), grob(pam), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
print(multiple_plot)

#METHOD_3
def.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(oma=c(0,0,3,0))#set top margin to have more space
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)
par(cex.axis = .7)

eclust(tsne_df, "kmeans", k = NClust)
fviz_silhouette(km)
eclust(tsne_df, "pam", k = NClust)
fviz_silhouette(pam)
```

I expected from either of the methods to get 4 plots with 2 clustering diagrams and 2 diagrams showing silhouette graphs, totalling to a grid of 2x2. However none of them seem to work with eclust plots, as they are a different object type and even by converting them to gList type it's still not working. I am new to R and can't figure out what an alternative method of plotting this would be. Please find the link below showing the outcome I am expecting, which I have put together manually in InDesign.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (wanted to plot 35 fviz_silhouette plots) and solved it using the `plot_grid` function from the `cowplot` package.

In your case maybe something like this (I am not sure where the left-hand side of the 2 x 2 plot comes from in your example, so I added the fviz_cluster function):

```
install.packages("cowplot")
library(cowplot)

# KMEANS -----------------------------

km <- eclust(tsne_df, "kmeans", k = NClust)
km.clus <- fviz_cluster(km)
km.sil <- fviz_silhouette(km)

# PAM CLUSTERING ---------------------
pam <- eclust(tsne_df, "pam", k = NClust)
pam.clus <- fviz_cluster(pam)
pam.sil <- fviz_silhouette(pam)

# PLOT -------------------------------

list.plot <- list() #list to store the plots
list.plot[[1]] <- km.clus
list.plot[[2]] <- km.sil    
list.plot[[3]] <- pam.clus
list.plot[[4]] <- pam.sil

plot_grid(plotlist = list.plot, ncol = 2)
```

Hope it works for you or anyone else having this problem.